# How to signal failure in trifecta parser

Tags: haskell, trifecta

As an experiment with trifecta I've written the following simple function:

```
filterParser :: (a -> Bool) -> Parser a -> Parser a
filterParser cond p = do
  a <- p
  if cond a 
    then return a 
    else unexpected "condition failed!"
```

The idea was to be able to add a condition to a parser. For example (assuming predicate `prime` already exists), you would write:
`filterParser prime integer` to create a parser that only accepts prime numbers.

---

With single parses it seems OK:

```
> parseString (filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "z"
> Success 'z

> parseString (filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "a"
> Failure (interactive):1:2: error: unexpected
> condition failed!
```

---

But with 'many' it doesn't work - compare:

```
> parseString (many $ filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "zzz2"
> Success "zzz"

> parseString (many $ filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "zzza"
> Failure (interactive):1:5: error: unexpected
> condition failed!
```

I was hoping the last example would also return `Success "zzz"`. The call to `unexpected` seems to de-rail the entire parse, which isn't what I wanted.

Comment: why don't you use [`satisfy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Char.html#satisfy) instead? - your parser does exactly what you told it - there is a difference between a `unexpected` failure and not consuming/parsing a character (as you demonstrated ;) )

Comment: `satisfy` would only work with chars. I wanted to write a function that would let me add a filter to _any_ parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `filterParser` recoverable by using [`try`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsers-0.12.3/docs/Text-Parser-Combinators.html#v:try):

```
import Text.Trifecta
import Control.Applicative

filterParser :: (a -> Bool) -> Parser a -> Parser a
filterParser cond p = try $ do
  x <- p
  if cond x then return x else empty
```

However, this would get rid of the custom parse error. Restoring that by using `unexpected "Condition failed"` in the `else` branch doesn't help either, because of the `try`.

Instead, we can reinstate the custom error message after the `try`:

```
filterParser :: (a -> Bool) -> Parser a -> Parser a
filterParser cond p = (<|> unexpected "Condition failed") $ try $ do
  x <- p
  if cond x then return x else empty
```

This works as expected:

```
*Main> parseString (many $ filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "zzza"
Success "zzz"
```

and

```
*Main> parseString (filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "a"
Failure (interactive):1:1: error: unexpected
    Condition failed
a<EOF>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution suggested by Cactus, there is the following:

---

```
filterParser :: (a -> Bool) -> Parser a -> Parser a
filterParser cond p = do
  a <- lookAhead p
  if cond a then p else unexpected "condition failed!"
```

---

This seems to give me what I want:

```
> parseString (filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "z"
> Success 'z'

> parseString (filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "4"
> Failure (interactive):1:1: error: expected: letter

> parseString (filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "a"
> Failure (interactive):1:1: error: unexpected
>     condition failed!

> parseString (many $ filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "zzz4"
> Success "zzz"

> parseString (many $ filterParser (> 'm') letter) mempty "zzza"
> Success "zzz"
```